# Error creating stored procedure when creating counter

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

When I run the following SQL

```
CREATE
PROCEDURE `Calendar`()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Cal` (
`month` INT(11) ,
`year` INT(11) 
);

SET @counter := -1;
WHILE (DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL @counter MONTH))) < DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH)))) DO 
INSERT INTO Cal SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH), INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 MONTH),'%m'),DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH), INTERVAL @counter + 1 MONTH),'%Y');
END WHILE;
END
```

to create and stored procedure, I get the following error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Any idea to fix the syntax error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks ok [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=367625503d4a4193d9cedc7120f8e1c1)

Comment: I'm running MySQL 5.7.23. Would that be the issue?

Comment: Try a `DELIMITER` @S.Sandeep

Comment: @RaymondNijland Tried. No luck

Comment: Your demo seams to be wierd @LukaszSzozda   try to run this one https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/otkh33kVNorH6dHoh8AkYy/0 .. It seams that website is using some kind of delimiter or executes the queries separated.. Also it errors on using DELIMITER see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6c0b998ea3d217f69a98799c85a6351 while the normal execution is https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/otkh33kVNorH6dHoh8AkYy/0

Comment: @RaymondNijland https://imgur.com/a/gCKrWmy

Comment: Looks like i forget to save it before i give the link it but it works without syntax error https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/otkh33kVNorH6dHoh8AkYy/1 @LukaszSzozda and topicstarter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Finally the stored procedure worked. But in the 12th month it says, 2018 instead of 2017

Comment: does the answer i giving in your other question help?