# Increased column value in one row

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure get the last 12 months from the current date in MySql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
PROCEDURE `Calendar`()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Cal` (
`month` INT(11) ,
`year` INT(11) 
);
TRUNCATE TABLE Cal;

SET @counter := -1;
WHILE (DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL @counter MONTH))) < DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH)))) DO 
INSERT INTO Cal SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH), INTERVAL @counter:=@counter + 1 MONTH),'%m'),DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH), INTERVAL @counter + 1 MONTH),'%Y');
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM `Cal`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Calendar;
```

The output table is

```
9   2017
10  2017
11  2017
12  2018
1   2018
2   2018
3   2018
4   2018
5   2018
6   2018
7   2018
8   2018
9   2018
```

In the month 12, the year is 2018. It should be 2017 and also the row `9    2017` shouldn't be there since its the 13th month including the current month. How can I make the 12th month's year to 2017 and remove the `9    2017` Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it the same as: [Error creating stored procedure when creating counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244246/error-creating-stored-procedure-when-creating-counter)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stored procedure that will give you the output you desire. It's longer but simpler than what you were attempting.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Calendar //
CREATE PROCEDURE Calendar ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE month INT DEFAULT MONTH(CURDATE());
  DECLARE year INT DEFAULT YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CAL (month INT, year INT);
  REPEAT
    SET month = month + 1;
    IF (month = 13) THEN
      SET month = 1;
      SET year = year + 1;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO CAL VALUES (month, year);
    UNTIL month = MONTH(CURDATE())
  END REPEAT;
  SELECT * FROM CAL;
  DROP TABLE CAL;
END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL Calendar();
```

Output:

```
 month  year    
 10     2017
 11     2017
 12     2017
  1     2018 
  2     2018
  3     2018
  4     2018
  5     2018
  6     2018
  7     2018
  8     2018
  9     2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without a creating a stored procedure, temporary table, inserting into temporary table and dropping the stored procedure after 
By using a number generator in MySQL code.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) AS `month`
 , YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) AS `year`
FROM (

 SELECT 
   (@NUMBER := @NUMBER + 1) AS number
 FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
  ) AS records_1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
  ) AS records_2
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @NUMBER := 0) AS init_user_params  
) AS number_generator
WHERE
    number_generator.number BETWEEN 1 AND 12
  AND
    MONTH(NOW()) <> MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) 
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) ASC
  , MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) ASC
```

**Results**

```
| month | year |
|-------|------|
|    10 | 2017 |
|    11 | 2017 |
|    12 | 2017 |
|     1 | 2018 |
|     2 | 2018 |
|     3 | 2018 |
|     4 | 2018 |
|     5 | 2018 |
|     6 | 2018 |
|     7 | 2018 |
|     8 | 2018 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/584

Note if you use MySQL 8.0+ the syntax is more clear using common table expressions.

**Query**

```
WITH RECURSIVE number_generator (number) AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT number + 1 FROM number_generator WHERE number < 12
)
SELECT 
   MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) AS `month`
 , YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) AS `year`
FROM 
 number_generator
WHERE
 MONTH(NOW()) <> MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) 
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) ASC
  , MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL number_generator.number MONTH) ASC
```

**Results**

```
| month | year |
|-------|------|
|    10 | 2017 |
|    11 | 2017 |
|    12 | 2017 |
|     1 | 2018 |
|     2 | 2018 |
|     3 | 2018 |
|     4 | 2018 |
|     5 | 2018 |
|     6 | 2018 |
|     7 | 2018 |
|     8 | 2018 |
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/chJ4qS2ocXS79vGkFBg7PR/13

Comment: Since I will be using the table created on this on another query. Is it possible to change the 2018 in the 12th month to 2017 in the stored procedure?

Comment: "Since I will be using the table created on this on another query" can you add a user case example to the question @damon then i can edit his question into a better one if you want.  "Is it possible to change the 2018 in the 12th month to 2017 in the stored procedure?"  let me see and test

Comment: "Is it possible to change the 2018 in the 12th month to 2017 in the stored procedure?" This code https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQEW2b6HUMyDw8vezinFGX/12 might work @damon could not test it it seams the server does not allow creating stored procedures. And i also dont have access to a MySQL server right now to test.

Comment: I still get an error. If you get access to a server please check if it works